# click event listener is working only for 1st list element and other sibling elements it's not

Tags: javascript

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vikramvi/pen/BaxQwaQ)

I'm new to JS and trying to achieve same action of adding new class using Event Listener to HTML elements but it's only working for 1st element and none of other 4 is working.

What mistake am I doing here ?

DOM Selectors

```
let rating_1 = document.getElementsByClassName("user-rating__rating-number-1")[0];
let rating_2 = document.getElementsByClassName("user-rating__rating-number-2")[0];
let rating_3 = document.getElementsByClassName("user-rating__rating-number-3")[0];
let rating_4 = document.getElementsByClassName("user-rating__rating-number-4")[0];
let rating_5 = document.getElementsByClassName("user-rating__rating-number-5")[0];
```

Working

```
rating_1.addEventListener("click", () => {

    rating_1.classList.add("user-rating__rating-number--orange");

});
```

Not Working

```
rating_2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //console.log(rating_2.innerText);

    //alert("clicked 2");

    rating_2.classList.add("user-rating__rating-number--orange");

});
```

EDIT :

- Culprit of this strange behavior is

> let ratingArray = [rating_1, rating_2, rating_3, rating_4,  rating_5];

When I do not use this array at all, I can click on each of the elements and assign new class to it; which is what I want to achieve.

- I've commented out `removeClassFromElements` to avoid any confusion / distraction from main problem
- But my question still remains unanswered why array of DOM selectors is not working as expected ? Why only 1st element of this array is able to accept new class name and not the others ?

I'm new to JavaScript coming from Java + Eclipse / IntelliJ world; it's so hard to debug issue with JS + VSCode ( any tips appreciated )

Comment: _"Not Working"_ - yes, working. At least in the version you have shown here, inside the question. What messes it up in your codepen, is that you execute `removeClassFromElements(rating_2);` at the end of the `rating_2` click handler callback, and that _remove_ the class you just set again. So go investigate why that one doesn't work as it should.

Comment: It would of course be much easier, if you did this the other way around. Instead of setting the class on the target element, and then afterwards figuring out which element it now does _not_ need to be removed from - remove it from all elements first, and then set it on the target element afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I've updated the question. Only 1st target element is able to accept new class and others are not. This weird behavior is happening when I've all the target elements inside an array so that I can use HOF to traverse and do needed action of removing class etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implemented `removeClassFromElements` in wrong way. you wanted to exclude current element from removal, but you send the element and not its index, therefore the splicing mechanism you used didn't work.
instead, filter the `ratingArray` comparing the excluded element itself:

```
const removeClassFromElements = (elementToExclude) => {
    ratingArray.filter(elem => elem != elementToExclude).forEach(element => element.classList.remove("user-rating__rating-number--orange"));
}
```

original code:

```
const removeClassFromElements = (elementToExclude) => {
    let newArray = ratingArray.slice();
    newArray.splice(elementToExclude, 1);

    newArray.forEach(element => element.classList.remove("user-rating__rating-number--orange"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the `background-color` from `white` to `orange` of these circles, what you can do is to assign a `common class name` (I've added the common class `test` but you can change to whatever you want) in your `html` code, and then with a `forEach` loop add the class name. Something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    item.classList.add("user-rating__rating-number--orange");
  })
})
```

```css
.user-rating__rating-number--orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.user-rating__rating-number > li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.user-rating__rating-number {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="user-rating__rating-number">
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-1 test">1</li>
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-2 test">2</li>
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-3 test">3</li>
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-4 test">4</li>
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-5 test">5</li>
</ul>
```

But this might not be good solution, because you might want for your user to select only one number. For example if a user selects `4` as initial feedback, but then he wants to change his rating to `2`, both numbers will have an orange background.

To prevent this you can have this in your JavaScript code, so the user can only select one number as rating.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (!item.classList.contains("user-rating__rating-number--orange")) {
      const allItems = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

      allItems.forEach(el => {
        if (el.classList.contains("user-rating__rating-number--orange")) {
          el.classList.remove("user-rating__rating-number--orange");
        }
      })
      item.classList.add("user-rating__rating-number--orange");
    }    
  })
})
```

```css
.user-rating__rating-number--orange {
  background-color: red;
}
.user-rating__rating-number > li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.user-rating__rating-number {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="user-rating__rating-number">
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-1 test">1</li>
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-2 test">2</li>
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-3 test">3</li>
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-4 test">4</li>
  <li class="user-rating__rating-number-5 test">5</li>
</ul>
```